# Boot repair disk on mint live usb

Tags: linux-mint, boot, dual-boot, boot-loader

I wanted to install Fedora in dual boot with windows. During the Fedora installation I installed a /boot partition and a /boot/efi partition.
The installation process was good and at starting the computer, then there was only one entry for booting fedora (but no entry for booting windows) in the boot menu.

Then I installed Debian to recover the grub and at the final step I didn't install any MBR on any partition of the computer (I installed it on the usb live ...).
Then there was no entry at all at the boot menu.

I really took care not to format any windows partition during the installation of these two distributions.

In the Bios setting, If I choose the windows manager booting, it doesn't boot. In the EFi setting, I have the same behavior.

Now I am using a Mint live usb to use the boot repair utility. Here is the boot info provided by this utility :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3wzFggFMh3/

Is it possible to recover the windows entry in the boot menu (I don't really care anymore about the linux (debian) entry) ?

Comment: What do you mean by " I didn't install any MBR on any partition of the computer (I installed it on the usb live ...)"?

Comment: at the end of the debian installer, he proposed you on which partition to install the MBR. Since I had GPT (I don't know if it's coming from windows or fedora, surely windows was in GPT table because it's UEFI) I didn't want to install the MBR so I choose the partition of my usb stick (/dev/sdb/) ... yeah not very intelligent but I thought I could install grub to deal with windows

Comment: What you install is not the MBR but the boot loader (GRUB). You won't be able to boot without it, and it has no point to install it on a USB, since it is not the disk where you have your OSs. Installing a distro to recover the GRUB is like a little overstretch. If I were you, instead of dealing with recovering the GRUB, which is not always an easy task, reinstall your OSs (if you don't have important data), And let the Linux installer deal with GRUB (install it on your hard disk!!). Install first Windows an then install Linux.

Comment: ok it was GRUB but then he asked on which partition should I install the Master Boot Record and it's him that I installed in the MBR because I knew I shouldn't use MBR but GPT. Could I have configure my partition table as GPT with the debian installer ? If I redo the debian installation and installed the MRB on the partition "/", windows would have had a boot menu or I could have configured it after ?

Comment: and also I didn't installed MBR on "/" because the debian installer didn't find the windows, he said something like :" It seems Debian is the same os on this computer [...]"